# Rerender after part of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have lots of data in an array and want to render all items in it.
This may take a while to render and therefore I want to insert a loading animation before the rendering starts.

The code looks something like this:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   // Start loading animation
   $loading.start();

   // Load objects into an array. These objects are 
   // rendered by the ng-repeat directive from angular
   $scope.array = data;
}
```

But when I execute the function foo, first ng-repeat renders all items and afterwards the loading animation starts.
How can I achieve a reversed behavior (First the loading animation and then the ng-repeat rendering)?

Comment: What is $loading? a service you create?

Comment: $loading is a service from this library: https://github.com/darthwade/angular-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $timeout to achieve it. In your code set timeout with load duration.

```
$scope.foo = function() {
  // Start loading animation
  $loading.start();

  $timeout(function() {
    // Load objects into an array. These objects are 
    // rendered by the ng-repeat directive from angular
    $scope.array = data;
  }, YOUR_LOAD_TIME);
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That already works, but there is still a huge delay until the loading animation triggers.
Do you have a suggestion how to fix that issue?

Comment: If you can create a fiddle or plunkr then it would be better.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
When creating the plunkr I realized, that I have to set a timeout to give the page time to rerender.
Your answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

Inject `$timeout` to the dependencies of the controller and then change the function to:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   // Start loading animation
   $loading.start();

   // Load objects into an array. These objects are 
   // rendered by the ng-repeat directive from angular
   $timeout(function() {
       $scope.array = data;
   });
}
```

The timeout will let the view refresh before you start the data processing